# Command-line access for office365 calendar

Tags: command-line, calendar, outlook

Using Alpine I can connect to office365 via IMAP, and I can *see* that there is a `Calendar/` folder in the IMAP collection. I can even kind of open them with Alpine, but it's super funky.

I can publish my office365 calendar, and download via ICS and import the meetings using `khal` or something, but that's kind of a gross process.

I'm looking for a tool that:

- is command-line or curses based
- can connect to my office365 calendar

I would *prefer* if I could get write-access to the calendar, but I'm OK if it's read only.

- if this tool supported both google calendar *and* outlook365 (including TODO/tasks) I'd be willing to pay for it
- At minimum it needs to support Linux, but cross-platform support would be a plus

Is there a tool like that out there yet?

Comment: What OS should it be for? What specific features do you need? Should it be free, or would you be willing to pay (how much)? Meanwhile: Also check Google for [imap calendar software](https://www.google.com/#q=imap+calendar+software) :)

Comment: Added that info. Looks like [Doug Hellman wrote something along these lines](https://doughellmann.com/blog/2007/10/01/working-with-imap-and-icalendar/) back in 2007.

Comment: Hm. If I'd better understand what you want to achieve... First thought is [imapsync](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/). [This MakeUseOf article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/organize-time-4-linux-calendar-apps/) has a few interesting pointers as well (Ctrl-F "command-line").

Comment: I actually looked at that, but (at least currently) "Imapsync can't migrate Contacts and Calendars." Which... is exactly what I want :P

Comment: @WayneWerner as a command line tool it would be extremely useful to know what you wanted to do with calendars - e.g. View next 10 upcoming events, view events for a specific week, view today's events?

Comment: @SteveBarnes Ideally? Not have to use the web interface. Ever :)

Comment: Hi there. maintainer of a O365 here. Now. when you say you are willing to pay for it. How much we talking? I might be able to provide you with such a piece of software.

Comment: Well, at this point I've developed a workaround where I just save the appointments from alpine, do `khal import /tmp/calendar.ics && vdirsyncer sync` with my Google Calendar, and that seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are python bindings called [o365](https://github.com/Narcolapser/python-o365), *(unfortunately currently unmaintained),* for interfacing to Office 365 that, with the examples given, would allow you, *from the command line,* to:

- Read & Send mail
- Access and Create events
- Manage Contacts

There is also a python CLI for Google Calendar [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/calendar-cli), *you do have to use [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project) to enable it before use but instructions are provided*, that currently will allow operations such as what is on today? `calendar-cli` or on any other specific date. Or with a little more work bindings such as [Google Drive Access](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/googleDriveAccess) also allow creating events as well as viewing them.

Of course you can use the [Microsoft "Graph" API](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/) *the python SDK is "coming soon"* &/or the [Google Python API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python#prerequisites) to roll your own.

Python and the bindings mentioned are:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Extensible
- Can work interactively, from command line scripts or with GUI front ends.

Comment: I was trying [`vdirsyncer`](https://vdirsyncer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which has similar requirements of enabling the app. I forked the o365 project, and may end out just rolling my own calendar app.